# Ajax request to controller

Tags: jquery, playframework

I'm new to Play and try some very simple things with AJAX. Right now I only want to send some data to my controller and send something back. I don't get how I can realize this in Play.

I used to send data with

```
$.get(url, {data:'input'), function() { do something });
```

to a standard servlet found at /url. In the servlet I have a simple

```
out.println("html output")
```

if I want to print something in my html file. I hope you get the point.

In Play I have a function in my controller (it's nonsense, just a test...)

```
public static void doIt(String input) {
    String out = input+"_foo";
    render(out);
}
```

I try to call this function with JQuery/AJAX like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      // when I click a button ...
      $("#send").click(function(){
            var url = #{jsAction @doIt(':input') /}     
            $.get(url({input: 'x'}), function() {
                ...
            });
      });
});
```

This is taken from the tutorial and doesn't work. Can somebody give me an idea how to write the controller and the JS to send some random string to my controller and return something.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `renderText()` instead of `render()`:

```
public static void doIt(String input) {
    String out = input + "_foo";
    renderText(out);
}
```

And try to explicitly define the controller you use if your view (where you write the script) does not belong to YourController:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // when I click a button ...
  $("#send").click(function(){
        var url = #{jsAction @YourController.doIt(':input') /}     
        $.get(url({input: 'x'}), function() {
            ...
        });
  });
```

});

It works for me. And important thing: This will only work at view file not separate js

Comment: I udnerstand what renderText does and why I should define the Controller. Thanks for that. Still, the jsAction thing does not work for me. But this does: $.get("doIt", {input:'test'}, function(data) { alert(data) }); I simply avoid the jsAction url and use a static one. Do you think this has any disadvantages? Now I need a route of course, so everybody can open the URL.

Comment: Where do you write your script? At html page or as separate.js?

Comment: As a separate script in public/javascript. I just figured out that jsAction works when I put it in the view itself. Do I always have to include it in the view or can I put in in a separate .js?

Comment: Hardcoding urls is bad idea. You can define all your urls in the view like that: var url = "@{YourController.doIt('x')}"; And then use it in your js file

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But how can I use a variable from the view in a separate .js? More precisely, why is it not possible to put a url definition with @{YourController.doIt('x')} in a separate .js?

Comment: You can use variables you are defined in view at all your js files - they are global. You can't put a url definition into js file because they are static files and are not touched by Play. But view files are for dynamic content and they are handled by framework. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it works now! I didn't know that I can simply use the variable in a static js file when I define it in the view.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the doc here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/ajax is not exactly clear. It says:"In this example we are requesting the list method from the default Application controller". But generally, you don't call the default Controller but one specific one.
So as Tim said, the best way is to specify the controller in your jsAction:

```
 #{jsAction @YourController.doIt(':input') /}
```

It should work!

Comment: I think I have a problem with the jsAction thing (see comment above). When I put var test = #{jsAction @YourController.doIt(':input') /} in any script (without any function except a test 'alert('foo')' it does not run. Do you have an idea what I get wrong with jsAction? Cheers

Comment: I have figured something out: Up to now I put jsAction in a separate .js file in public/javascript and included it in the template. It didn't work as described above. When I put it in the view itself, it seems to be woring. Any idea why? Thanks and cheers

Comment: yes I think it is because the javascript is simply not interpreted by the template engine... it doesn't scan your included javascript files and I think it's the right behavior :)...